# Code first in entity framework set column to type datetime2 in sql server

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, datetime2

I have a value

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2015-10-12 14:24:40.582");
```

with it I do:

```
SomeEntity someEntity = new SomeEntity() 
{
    ID = 1, 
    ChangedOn = dt
};
context.SomeEntities.Add(someEntity);
```

What I found out: in database table the value stored is "2015-10-12 14:24:40.58**3**0000"

I found it out manually with

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime2, ChangedOn) FROM SomeEnititiesTable WHERE ID=1;
```

I load someEntity from database and do

```
bool ok = someEntity.ChangedOn.Equals(dt);
```

The problem is that `ok == false` when I expect `ok == true`. :|

**How to make *code first* in entity framework generate column of type datetime2 instead of datetime in migrations?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

1) Add a field ChangedOn2 with type of long.

2) Save dt.Ticks value to ChangedOn2.

3) Compare with

```
someEntity.ChangedOn2.Equals(dt.Ticks);
```

Answer (score 6):

> How to make code first in entity framework generate column of type `datetime2` instead of `datetime` in migrations?

To specify the type of the column to use you can add the following attribute to the property `ChangedOn` of your model:

```
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
```

Or if you are using the Fluent API then you can add this to your `OnModelCreating` of your `DBContext`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    // ...

    modelBuilder.Entity<someEntity>()
        .Property(p => p.ChangedOn)
        .HasColumnType("datetime2");

    // ...
}
```